# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed with LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: android

I use `BroadcastReceiver` with `LocalBrodcastManager` to track data changes and update view.
Code example below:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            doSomeStaff();
        }
    };

    private void doSomeStaff() {
        //Do some staff with activity
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

Rarely I have the next crash:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1470)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:634)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:617)
```

I thinks its because I have a googleMap at screen and show/hide it according to data state.
Example:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .show(mMapFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: You can check if activity was destroyed with [`isDetroyed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isDestroyed())

Comment: I know, the root of issues is why receiver is called if onStop goes before onDestroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the simplest solution that exists right now is to surround your onReceive with a isDestroyed() check.

```
BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (!isDestroyed) {
           doSomeStaff();
        }
    }
};
```